# Initialize std::list<CustomType> from std::initializer_list<std::string_view> in ctor's member initializer list

Tags: c++, c++17, string-view, member-initialization, stdinitializerlist

I have a `Game` class that stores the `m_players` as a data member (`std::list<Player>`) and each player has multiple data members, one of them being their `m_name` (`std::string`). When instantiating a game I want the user to provide the players' names. I want them to be able to use string literals or strings, so I think using a `std::string_view` is the best practice here (right?). I also want the game to be playable with an arbitrary number of players, so I think a `std::initializer_list` for the game's ctor's parameters is the way to go (right?). Below you find the code ([godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYgATKVpMGoZAFI9AIQuXSS%2BsgJ4BlRugDCqWgFcWDEADMGqRuADJ4DJgAcr4ARpjEgQDspAAOqAqEzgyePn6BwemZTgLhkTEs8YkB0vaYjtlCBEzEBLm%2B/kF2mA4lDE0tBGXRcQnJds2t7fldCpNDESOVYzUAlHao3sTI7BwWARHIPlgA1GYB7s5zxJis59hmGgCC%2B4fHmGcX1xHA948vegODCO3lO53ctDwcz%2Bz3%2B/2u3kcJ2URgAngk4UlrM8TrjkWiEicIHN0CAQN8TAB9ABueEwAHcTsw2Kt/niTiATixKczMGYsbz%2BQARNl4/nWJIi2HPVLEPDUpgEdii3EkskU4BcnmsPkBbEvSXnfX/I5MBQKE4AcR1mP1qW8sUhyBAKqtOogaAYcxOapAESyYjwAC8EpTIdCvgRSeSCHKqbSGfcTqkCcQFKycXjOdyU0x0Wnxbn8wpha7xa72QB6SsnfjEIme71MbxECwANmTqY5nbzCXTFbx1bOWIHuKH7JzqYUADpMCxcztKbEmMgANYQIsJVl60cnIelzO4g8vGVyhVKl2Hn1RsnhgjglG94hJydPks72GGj8np4RAhcpgIggDMDX1dlrTYE5gB1Lhyz0PQngYBgLAMM54MsVBYhQ0tv3ZX0NSZGC4IQpDsK/MC8Xw2MfkItg9GIjCsPgnCKNxCCPmgujxV5LhSFozB6PIzEpSeDh1loTgAFZeH8DgtFIVBOHcGwbB9TZtg%2BfY9F4AhNDE9ZV0CAJpwCUyzPM8y20MThJBkvSFM4XgFBAYJdLksTSDgWAYEQFBUHnOgEnISg0AC%2BhElNKlY28BhVz4OglTTShYns2IIhaVFOB4Ug0uYYhUQAeVibR6jc7LQrYQQCoYWhMvc0gsFibxgHcMRaGc7heCwFhjGAcR6vwG4GmpTAOvkzBVHqFtdnkv8ensyFYmIDLPCwezqJYLKPKoIxgAUAA1Ol6QK1JGC2mRBBEMR2CkC75CUNR7N0AJDF6lAVKsQw8FiZzYF5EBYlQDICFIEbEm4AAOWzVnWVBUj6DqAFoSXOIVzCsGw9A0E5EYAdUwMHUQIBAaLxhhUER9HrCsABOCHKf81JFRx3Hycpj7LDphn50VRHTvQYwnGQXhUDBuUsF%2B4Dul6bJXAYDwvA6CQQnl4YKiqZWiiyARpn8Xitb6NXRkSXi6gaAQBimRX8lNnpSsaeYjeWE2JkGXXlbmQYnY1rh1gUdSdn0cSpLs%2BrFI4E5VAhttEbbSQTkizUIGi2LViJXBCBINCAj0VYdL0mHSEM0yTIssvTOsjhbNITbJOCWT5PDpyXNINytHWLzfM2Ah7RBigPUZwLiCiHVOCjmO44TowTCJFPVzzkJ8CIcX9Duq7xFu/hBEUFR1Hq57SHpZbUi24OOGk0gG5FzgCpbXuTlQKhI%2Bj2P48T2fiBi%2BeiU8MLCX2AIC8276VIAgW4WBEhSwklXXgtd672SbnYFuwDC7F2MuXcuVloEBFDo3RyrcC6eR8p3CASBQqpCHsFAef9Eh7WYKkBQCBUAgxoLQRKzkIApXqrlDK50eH5SKiVRw50KqMAINVWq9lGrNVarQdq51uq9X6vJQa9sRpjV4BNKaF56pzWgfJRay18qrRmjpOUm1OrrB2kwPah0GQnTOp1NeogN7SC3vdXeT1lbT1MBzL6P14AQH%2BoDYGoMxiQ2hrDeG2QkYowCGjDmWMWZtRZhNWMTAWaMKYOgVAjIyYCERrSVo3gxCI3QMvHG/NBZ4GQCzGK3glDoBFmLPAEt4B%2BztubfwEA3Du14mERY6sxj6wyNrHI1s9ZpFGYbQZxsPadL6JbNoEz5kywto7WZzsPbzD6a7Vo3thl%2BwDuwXOlcL5XwchHcer8oLIFqcnT%2Bqd05LyzlpIBBcDJGVLhg8yldq5wMvgg/BzlXKEJIUgbuvcqHkKHiPNgY8X6T2AHcj%2BX8F6YBeSvAw7j143TcbIHej197KyPkwE%2Blizm4OvhwW%2BPcWwPyftcpFKKHlop/oPcK2dfb53coXMB2SxhQJsrAkAddAVh2Bcgj5Rcvk/IspXHB4q8EcB5e3M%2B2klXUtVSAsGmQXCSCAA)) I thought would work, but which gives me an error for the line of code trying to initialize `m_players`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>


struct Player
{
    Player (std::string_view name)
    : m_name{name}
    {}

private:
    std::string m_name;
};

class Game
{
public:
    Game(const std::initializer_list<std::string_view> players)
    // error: no matching function for call to 'std::__cxx11::list<Player>::list(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
    : m_players{players}
    {}

private:
    std::list<Player> m_players;
};

int main()
{
    Game game1{"Ann", "Bob"};

    std::string name1{"Ann"};
    std::string name2{"Bob"};
    Game game2{name1, name2};
}
```

Two things work:

1. Instead of using the member initializer list I can write this loop:
   for (const auto& player : players)
   {
   m_players.emplace_back(player);
   }
2. If I use a fixed number of string views as input parameters instead of a std::initializer_list that works as well.

I don't know what's happening in the member initializer list, so I don't understand why this doesn't work. I thought the compiler would basically do exactly what the loop in the ctor body would do but my guess is that this is some kind of implicit casting issue?

If I'm not mistaking it shouldn't make a difference performancewise whether I use the member initializer list or the body with a loop, but I'm still curious why this doesn't work.

Comment: Unrelated: Why use list and not vector?

Comment: Use the constructor that takes iterators: `m_players(players.begin(), players.end())`

Comment: You are calling the list constructor with the argument initializer_list - you can see the full error message (candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'const std::initializer_list<std::string_view>' (aka 'const initializer_list<basic_string_view<char>>') to 'const allocator_type' (aka 'const std::allocator<Player>') for 1st argument)

Comment: @kiner_shah the players take turns (it's a board game) and the best fit would probably be a circular buffer, because if i increase the iterator (`current_player`) past the last player it would point to the first one. I guess there's no reason to use `std::list` though.

Comment: @super thank you, that fixes the issue :) I still don't know what the actual problem is (how the member initializer list gets interpreted) and why you suggestion solves this.

Comment: @RobLauer, it seems you fix the number of players first and then no additions/removals to number of players happen. Better to use a vector and for iterating, just using modulo. If 4 players, it will be like `i = (i+1)%4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at cpp reference I think I finally understand the issue.
The member initializer list just calls the corresponding ctor for each data member, which in my case is a `std::list` ctor.
No matter what I choose as an input type (strings or string literals), the type of the ctor's input parameter (`players`) is `const std::initializer_list<std::string_view>` (T = std::string_view).
`m_players` is of type `std::list<Player>` (T = Player) and if you check the documentation of the `std::list` container you'll find that it offers several ctors and one of them accepts a `std::initializier_list<T>` where `T` is the same type as the one for `std::list<T>`. In my case they are different though (std::string_view != Player) and that's the issue.
One way to solve this is to use a different ctor as proposed by @super.

```
: m_players{players.begin(), players.end()}
```

will call this ctor:

```
template< class InputIt >
list( InputIt first, InputIt last,
      const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::list<T>` be constructed from a `std::initializer_list<T>` but `Game` takes a `std::initializer_list<std::string_view>`. As far as C++ is concerned, two different template instantiations of a template class are completely separate types and have no relation to each other. This is why it is not possible to convert from `std::initializer_list<std::string_view>` to `std::initializer_list<Player>` even though `Player` is implicitly constructible from `std::string_view`.

Note that this works:

```
std::list<Player> players{"Anna", "Bob"};
```

while this doesn't:

```
std::initializer_list<std::string_view> names = {"Anna", "Bob"};
std::list<Player> players{names};
```

Because in the first example, the [brace-enclosed initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) is converted to `std::initializer_list<Player>`, required by `std::list`. But in the second example the brace-enclosed initializer list is converted to a `std::initializer_list<std::string_view>` and then there is no way to convert it back.

Following the recommendation from @super and writing `m_players{players.begin(), players.end()}` calls `std::list`s constructor which takes two iterators.